# Generated sigma field by random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am looking at two generated sigma fields. Suppose Y is a random variable defined on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. Then let's consider $\sigma(Y)$ and $\sigma({Y\leq t:t\in\mathbb{R}})$ and I try to prove these two sigma fields are equivalent.

With Dynkin's $\pi-\lambda$ theorem, I can prove that $\sigma(Y\leq t:t\in\mathbb{R})\subseteq\sigma(Y)$, but how to prove another direction?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: When you write $\sigma\big( Y\leq t: t\in \mathbb{R} \big)$, do you mean the sigma algebra generated by the indicator function of these events?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur: Yes. Just like $\sigma(Y) = \{ Y^{-1}(B): B \in \mathcal{B}(R)\}$. So $\sigma(Y\leq t) = \{Y^{-1}((-\infty,t]):t\in\mathcal{R}\}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460854/sigma-algebra-generated-by-a-random-variable?rq=1 does this answer your question?

Comment: @blamethelag: I think it does. It's an application of the good sets principle. Really thanks!